# Ruby: assert error message produced by a subclass of Set

Tags: ruby, error-handling, set, assert

```
require 'set'
require 'test/unit'
class Foo < Set
  def to_s
    "to_s"
  end
  alias_method :inspect, :to_s
end

class FooTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test1
    assert_equal(Foo.new, false)
  end
end
```

Expected output:

```
test1(FooTest) [test.rb:12]: <to_s> expected but was <false>.
```

Actual output:

```
test1(FooTest) [test.rb:12]: <#<Foo: {}>> expected but was <false>.
```

### Edit

Test::Unit uses a strange method called pretty_inspect, which I hear of the first time. Nevertheless, this code will work as expected:

Solution:

```
require 'set'
require 'test/unit'
class Foo < Set
  def to_s
    "to_s"
  end
  alias_method :pretty_inspect, :to_s
end

class FooTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test1
    assert_equal(Foo.new, false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, Max.  When referencing methods, particularly unfamiliar ones, you may want to include the class or module, with a link: [Kernel#pretty_inspect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/Kernel.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test/unit appears to not rely on an object's `to_s` or `inspect` method. Looking at the source, it may be accessing the object's class `inspect` method directly, but my attempts to redefine `Set`s `inspect` instance method didn't work either.  Check out the source of test/unit. ;-)